# imagecreatefromjpeg() scaling a image

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm building a image scaler that uses jcrop a jQuery plugin and php and ajax to upload and crop/scale images. I keep having a random error when he should save and crop/scale the image, the problem is random because I can use the same image 10 times, crop it the same way and same size and it works 9 out of 10 times but the times that it doesn't work I get this error:

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file
>   in **/home/users/A006193/fgpostbus.nl/www.fgpostbus.nl/uploader/scale.php** on line **9**
>
> Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: 'upload/cfd962453a1409fd59dfd5e6230e869eheaderFac12348.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in **/home/users/A006193/fgpostbus.nl/www.fgpostbus.nl/uploader/scale.php** on line **9**
>
> Warning:  imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in **/home/users/A006193/fgpostbus.nl/www.fgpostbus.nl/uploader/scale.php** on line **13**

the image gets saved with md5, after that you have to crop it if it isnt the required size it has to have when cropped the data gets send to scale.php
scale.php contains the php to perform the last actions (crop, scale and save) i use ajax to post the details the php should use. it gets send like this:

```
x=354&y=0&w=245&h=245&url=upload%2Fcfd962453a1409fd59dfd5e6230e869eheaderFac12348.jpg&setW=160&setH=160
```

finaly my scale.php looks like this:

```
<?php

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$src = $_POST['url'];
$targ_w = $_POST['setW'];
$targ_h = $_POST['setH'];
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

imagejpeg($dst_r, $src, 90);
exit;
}

?>
```

the problem is doing my head in sinds it doesnt have any patern of giving the error, im getting it completly random so if anyone would have a suggestion what i could be doing wrong then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is this path `upload%2Fcfd962453a1409fd59dfd5e6230e869eheaderFac12348.jpg` is on the server side ?

Because if not, you need to upload the actual binary file; only passing the filename in the URL won't work.

You may want to look here: [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: But it *could* work if you pass the URL of the image and your PHP is properly configured.

Comment: yea its the path on the server

Comment: Also, the second parameter of [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagejpeg.php) is the path to save the file to. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: save the new cropped/scalled image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assuming that the image and remote server are working as expected, you should use curl to download the image locally and then process it, handling any errors you may come across along the way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
```

before 
**imagecreatefromjpeg()**